# python flask javascript DELETE 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add a button to delete a musical venue from my postgres database with flask-sqlalchemy on that venue's page and then redirect to the homepage but I'm getting the error

```
DELETE ip 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
```

in my console and

```
[28/May/2020
14:12:49] "DELETE /deletevenue/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
72.133.209.13 - - [28/May/2020
14:12:50] "DELETE / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

in my terminal.  I don't know what is going wrong.  I can see that the correct venue_id is being sent to the route but I'm still getting this error.  I don't know what's wrong here.  This is the relevant code:

app.py

```
@app.route('/deletevenue/<venue_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_venue(venue_id):
  error = False
  venue = db.session.query(Venue).filter_by(id=venue_id).one()
  name = venue.name
  try:
    Venue.query.filter_by(id=venue_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()
  except:
    error = True
    db.session.rollback()
  finally:
    db.session.close()
  if error:
    flash('An Error occured.  The venue ' + name + ' could not be deleted.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
  else:
    flash('Success.  Venue ' + name + ' was deleted.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('pages/home.html')
```

show_venue.html

```
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="deleteArtist" data-id="{{ venue.id }}">Delete this Artist</button>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    const btn = document.getElementById('deleteArtist');
    btn.onclick = function(e) {
        venue_id = e.target.dataset['id'];
        console.log(venue_id)
        let r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this venue?");
        if (r == true) {
            fetch('/deletevenue/' + venue_id, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
        }
    }

</script>
```

How can I get this button working?

Comment: This log mean your request call to route *index* instead of route * delete_venue*

`14:12:50] "DELETE / HTTP/1.1" 405 -`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. redirect() is flask => return response_code: 302 with same method it's recieved. (HERE is DELETE) => so it's redirect to `index route` with method DELETE => 405.
2. Method [fetch()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) return a Promise => It's need a result response, you can not redirect code like:

```py
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

It should return json or something like value, then use your javascript code check value => redirect. - [How TO - Redirect to Another Webpage](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp)